# Chome USB debug: Pending authentication: please accept debugging session on the device

Tags: google-chrome, usb-debugging

Chome USB debug: Pending authentication: please accept debugging session on the device.

The confirm dialog is gone accidentally. How to show it again on android phone?

Tried:

```
 reload chrome://inspect/#devices, 
 Uncheck/check "Discover USB devices"
 disconnect/reconnect usb cable,  
 Developer options (off/on "Allow USB debugging")
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. This is what I did to resolve the problem:

- In my `~/.android` directory, I removed `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub`.
- Revoked previous authorizations using "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" menu in developer options.
- While the USB was still connected to my PC, I turned off and then on "USB debugging" in developer options.
- After these steps, a dialog appeared allowing RSA key exchange, selected to remember my credential on this PC. Also, I disabled adb authorization timeout option.
- If nothing works in your case, consider changing the USB cable.
- Another issue may be related to the ports that Node uses to establish adb server through the Chrome browser. Ensure that these ports are not using by other software processes. You can change the default ports through the `Configure...` option in `chrome://inspect/#devices`.

[image]

- Another hint: if you are trying to authorize the device outside of Chrome, you should execute your adb command in user mode, not root mode because your `.android` folder is created in your user directory in home. So, exchanging or creating a key requires you to work in user mode (the same user as denoted in your home directory).